# cy.exec('/bin/ls') fails with exit code 1

Tags: cypress

When I run `cy.exec('/bin/ls')` this fails with exit code 1. It does not seems to matter what the command is, the exit code is always 1.

Some (maybe) relevant info:

When I ran `node_modules/.bin/cypress open`, I got this error:

```
cypress:cli spawn args [ '--no-sandbox', '--', '--project', '/Users/mingxiao/workspace/deploy-acp-poc', '--cwd', '/Users/mingxiao/workspace/deploy-acp-poc' ] { detached: false, stdio: 'inherit' } +0ms
/Users/mingxiao/Library/Caches/Cypress/6.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Cypress: bad option: --no-sandbox
```

*However* if I run with `sudo`, that error does not surface and it successfully runs.